# Visualizar documento em pdf usando o printdocument

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo uma impressão direto na impressora usando o printdocument, agora preciso usar este documento para gerar um pdf, e visualizar usando o pdf do Windows, como faço pra passar o meu código para pdf.

segue o código que gero a impressão com printdocumet

```
private void prt_implaudos_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        string cabecalho = "CERTIFICADO DE ANÁLISE";
        string referencia = "REFERÊNCIA: ESPECIFICAÇÃO DO FORNECEDOR";
        string resultfrase = "RESULTADO: APROVADO DE ACORDO COM ESPECIFCAÇÕES DO FABRICANTE";
        string data = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        Pen linhaPreta = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
        Point ponto1 = new Point(30, 185);
        Point ponto2 = new Point(800, 185);

        Point ponto3 = new Point(30, 280);
        Point ponto4 = new Point(800, 280);

        Point ponto5 = new Point(30, 945);
        Point ponto6 = new Point(800, 945);

        Image imagem = Image.FromFile(string.Format("{0}{1}", Application.StartupPath, "\\Imagens\\logo PScor1.jpg"));
        Image imagem1 = Image.FromFile(string.Format("{0}{1}", Application.StartupPath, "\\Imagens\\AssinaturaLaudo1.jpg"));

        e.Graphics.DrawString(data, letra, cor, new Point(710, 950));

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(imagem, 50, 0);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(cabecalho, letra3, cor, new Point(280, 0));

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(linhaPreta, ponto1, ponto2);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(linhaPreta, ponto3, ponto4);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(linhaPreta, ponto5, ponto6);

        int f = 60;
        foreach (string nota in implaudos1)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(nota, letra, cor, new Point(600, f));
            f += 15;
        }

        int y = 60;
        foreach (string laudops in implaudos)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(laudops, letra, cor, new Point(50, y));
            y += 15;
        }
        int h = 90;
        foreach (string laudos3 in implaudos3)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(laudos3, letra, cor, new Point(600, h));
            h += 15;
        }
        int g = 160;
        foreach (string quimico in implaudos2)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(quimico, letra, cor, new Point(50, g));
            g += 15;
        }
        int b = 190;
        foreach (string manu in manuseio)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(manu, letra4, cor, new Point(50, b));
            b += 15;
        }
        int c = 220;
        foreach (string derra in derramamento)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(derra, letra4, cor, new Point(50, c));
            c += 15;
        }
        int d = 250;
        foreach (string trata in tratamento)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(trata, letra4, cor, new Point(50, d));
            d += 15;
        }
        int x = 290;
        foreach (string caracter in caracteristicas)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(caracter, letra1, cor, new Point(50, x));
            x += 17;
        }
        foreach (string caracter1 in caracteristicas1)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(caracter1, letra2, cor, new Point(50, x));
            x += 20;
        }
        int w = 290;
        foreach (string especific in especificacoes)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(especific, letra1, cor, new Point(280, w));
            w += 17;
        }
        foreach (string especific1 in especificacoes1)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(especific1, letra2, cor, new Point(280, w));
            w += 20;
        }
        int z = 290;
        foreach (string result in resultados)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(result, letra1, cor, new Point(530, z));
            z += 17;
        }
        foreach (string result1 in resultados1)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(result1, letra2, cor, new Point(530, z));
            z += 20;
        }
        int a = 290;
        foreach (string metod in metodos)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(metod, letra1, cor, new Point(680, a));
            a += 17;
        }
        foreach (string metod1 in metodos1)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(metod1, letra2, cor, new Point(680, a));
            a += 20;
        }
        if (Convert.ToInt32(txt_produto.Text) == 002828 && Convert.ToInt32(txt_produto.Text) == 001019)
        {
            int j = 935;
            foreach (string insumos1 in insumos)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(insumos1, letra2, cor, new Point(500, j));
                j += 15;
            }
        }

        e.Graphics.DrawString(referencia, letra2, cor, new Point(50, 950));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(resultfrase, letra2, cor, new Point(50, 965));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(imagem1, 150, 980);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisará de uma biblioteca externa para fazer isso, chamada [PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/). É a que mais recebe elogios na plataforma .NET. Após incluir a biblioteca no projeto, terá que converter `Graphics -> Image -> PDF Document`.

Nesse código é complicado, pois não conseguimos redirecionar o `Graphics` para duas instâncias gráficas ao mesmo tempo que seriam no caso **a impressão e a imagem do PDF**. Então vamos implementar dois `Graphics`.

Criarei um `Graphics b` que irá funcionar em pararelo ao `e.Graphics`, um em cima do outro, o mesmo código:

```
private void prt_implaudos_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // imagem que será convertida para o PDF
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(e.Graphics.DpiX, e.Graphics.DpiY);

    // gráficos da imagem do PDF
    Graphics bg = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

    string cabecalho = "CERTIFICADO DE ANÁLISE";
    string referencia = "REFERÊNCIA: ESPECIFICAÇÃO DO FORNECEDOR";
    string resultfrase = "RESULTADO: APROVADO DE ACORDO COM ESPECIFCAÇÕES DO FABRICANTE";
    string data = DateTime.Now.ToString();

    Pen linhaPreta = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
    Point ponto1 = new Point(30, 185);
    Point ponto2 = new Point(800, 185);

    Point ponto3 = new Point(30, 280);
    Point ponto4 = new Point(800, 280);

    Point ponto5 = new Point(30, 945);
    Point ponto6 = new Point(800, 945);

    Image imagem = Image.FromFile(string.Format("{0}{1}", Application.StartupPath, "\\Imagens\\logo PScor1.jpg"));
    Image imagem1 = Image.FromFile(string.Format("{0}{1}", Application.StartupPath, "\\Imagens\\AssinaturaLaudo1.jpg"));

    e.Graphics.DrawString(data, letra, cor, new Point(710, 950));
    bg.DrawString(data, letra, cor, new Point(710, 950));

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(imagem, 50, 0);
    bg.DrawImage(imagem, 50, 0);

    e.Graphics.DrawString(cabecalho, letra3, cor, new Point(280, 0));
    bg.DrawString(cabecalho, letra3, cor, new Point(280, 0));

    e.Graphics.DrawLine(linhaPreta, ponto1, ponto2);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(linhaPreta, ponto3, ponto4);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(linhaPreta, ponto5, ponto6);

    bg.DrawLine(linhaPreta, ponto1, ponto2);
    bg.DrawLine(linhaPreta, ponto3, ponto4);
    bg.DrawLine(linhaPreta, ponto5, ponto6);

    int f = 60;
    foreach (string nota in implaudos1)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(nota, letra, cor, new Point(600, f));
        bg.DrawString(nota, letra, cor, new Point(600, f));
        f += 15;
    }

    int y = 60;
    foreach (string laudops in implaudos)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(laudops, letra, cor, new Point(50, y));
        bg.DrawString(laudops, letra, cor, new Point(50, y));
        y += 15;
    }
    int h = 90;
    foreach (string laudos3 in implaudos3)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(laudos3, letra, cor, new Point(600, h));
        bg.DrawString(laudos3, letra, cor, new Point(600, h));
        h += 15;
    }
    int g = 160;
    foreach (string quimico in implaudos2)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(quimico, letra, cor, new Point(50, g));
        bg.DrawString(quimico, letra, cor, new Point(50, g));
        g += 15;
    }
    int b = 190;
    foreach (string manu in manuseio)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(manu, letra4, cor, new Point(50, b));
        bg.DrawString(manu, letra4, cor, new Point(50, b));
        b += 15;
    }
    int c = 220;
    foreach (string derra in derramamento)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(derra, letra4, cor, new Point(50, c));
        bg.DrawString(derra, letra4, cor, new Point(50, c));
        c += 15;
    }
    int d = 250;
    foreach (string trata in tratamento)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(trata, letra4, cor, new Point(50, d));
        bg.DrawString(derra, letra4, cor, new Point(50, c));
        d += 15;
    }
    int x = 290;
    foreach (string caracter in caracteristicas)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(caracter, letra1, cor, new Point(50, x));
        bg.DrawString(caracter, letra1, cor, new Point(50, x));
        x += 17;
    }
    foreach (string caracter1 in caracteristicas1)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(caracter1, letra2, cor, new Point(50, x));
        bg.DrawString(caracter1, letra2, cor, new Point(50, x));
        x += 20;
    }
    int w = 290;
    foreach (string especific in especificacoes)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(especific, letra1, cor, new Point(280, w));
        bg.DrawString(especific, letra1, cor, new Point(280, w));
        w += 17;
    }
    foreach (string especific1 in especificacoes1)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(especific1, letra2, cor, new Point(280, w));
        bg.DrawString(especific1, letra2, cor, new Point(280, w));
        w += 20;
    }
    int z = 290;
    foreach (string result in resultados)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(result, letra1, cor, new Point(530, z));
        bg.DrawString(result, letra1, cor, new Point(530, z));
        z += 17;
    }
    foreach (string result1 in resultados1)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(result1, letra2, cor, new Point(530, z));
        bg.DrawString(result1, letra2, cor, new Point(530, z));
        z += 20;
    }
    int a = 290;
    foreach (string metod in metodos)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(metod, letra1, cor, new Point(680, a));
        bg.DrawString(metod, letra1, cor, new Point(680, a));
        a += 17;
    }
    foreach (string metod1 in metodos1)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(metod1, letra2, cor, new Point(680, a));
        bg.DrawString(metod1, letra2, cor, new Point(680, a));
        a += 20;
    }
    if (Convert.ToInt32(txt_produto.Text) == 002828 && Convert.ToInt32(txt_produto.Text) == 001019)
    {
        int j = 935;
        foreach (string insumos1 in insumos)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(insumos1, letra2, cor, new Point(500, j));
            bg.DrawString(insumos1, letra2, cor, new Point(500, j));
            j += 15;
        }
    }

    e.Graphics.DrawString(referencia, letra2, cor, new Point(50, 950));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(resultfrase, letra2, cor, new Point(50, 965));
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(imagem1, 150, 980);

    bg.DrawString(referencia, letra2, cor, new Point(50, 950));
    bg.DrawString(resultfrase, letra2, cor, new Point(50, 965));
    bg.DrawImage(imagem1, 150, 980);
}
```

Pronto, no código acima convertemos seu código inteiro para um Bitmap. Agora vamos converter o Bitmap para PDF.

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(); // cria o documento pdf
doc.Pages.Add(new PdfPage()); // adiciona uma nova página ao PDF
XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]); // cria os gráficos da página
XImage img = XImage.FromImage(bmp); // extrai uma imagem do bitmap criado

xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0); // escreve a imagem no PDF na posição 0, 0
doc.Save("C:\\PDF_gerado.pdf"); // salva o PDF para este caminho
doc.Close(); // fecha o arquivo
```

---

- [Convertendo arquivos de imagens para PDF (externo)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28609/Converting-Image-Files-to-PDF)
- [PDFsharp image to XImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44347809/pdfsharp-image-to-ximage)
- [código fonte do PDFsharp](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=pdfsharp) - *a documentação está embutida no código fonte.*

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção Cypher, desculpa pela bagunça do código, sou um iniciante ainda, mas no seu codigo acima estou com erroo em duas partes essa esta pedido par converter para string e float (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(e.Graphics.DpiX, e.Graphics.DpiY); e esta outra não esta achando imagem (XImage img = XImage.FromImage(bmp);

Comment: Não esta achando o FromImage(bmp).